# Composite key and many to one

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping

I need a field to be part of the composite key, but I also need a Many to one relationship with the corresponding object. Is something like this possible ?

```
@Entity
public class Instrument {

    @EmbeddedId
    private InstrumentPk instrumentPk;

    @ManyToOne;
    private Transaction transaction;

}

@Embeddable
public class InstrumentPk {

    private Integer productId;

    private Integer transId;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case `@ManyToOne` relationship has nothing to do with `@Embeddable`:

```
@ManyToOne;
private Transaction transaction;
```

This is goig to work just fine provided there is a `Transaction` entity and mapping is well defined.